# Javascript get 100vh in pixels

Tags: javascript, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='height:4000px;background:#EEE;'>
            <div id=vh style='height:100vh;background:#AFB'>
                100vh
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button onclick='show()' style='font-size:55px'>
                    Show
                </button>
            </div>
            more stuff
        </div>
        <script>
            var vh=document.getElementById('vh')
            function show()
            {
                alert('window.innerHeight='+window.innerHeight
                +', window.outerHeight='+window.outerHeight
                +', screen.height='+screen.height
                +', document.documentElement.clientHeight='+document.documentElement.clientHeight
                +', vh.clientHeight='+vh.clientHeight)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://curtastic.com/testvh.html

On my iPad the 100vh div size is 1256 pixels. (if your most recent scroll was upward)

window.innerHeight is 1217.

screen.height is 1024.

window.outerHeight is 0.

documentElement.clientHeight is 4016.

Is there any way in javascript of getting this number 1256? Besides making a div and setting it to height:100vh then checking its clientHeight?

I also have my font size set to 10vh. What is that exactly in pixels?

I am not using jQuery.

I know that 100vh is taller than the visible viewport on purpose on mobile so that the browser bars can change size without altering vh. So I want the size of the screen regardless of the browser bars, which is what vh does.

[image]

Comment: It **should** be `documentElement.clientHeight`; it is for me. Not sure how you're getting 4016 there...

Comment: I'm also getting 4016 on chrome and firefox on windows.

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: I didn't down-vote myself, so can't say for sure, but I guess it was because others couldn't replicate the problem? Like I say, I can't replicate the problem myself; `documentElement.clientHeight` gives the correct results for me. Maybe try providing a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself and confirm the problem still exists there? :)

Comment: I already provided a minimal complete verifiable example, with code and also a link to a webpage just to test it. I have already confirmed that the problem exists on several devices.

Comment: Can you update your page to also show `window.document.body.clientHeight` ?

Comment: Ok done. It gives me the same as window.innerHeight

Comment: See if this cross browser library is of any help? https://github.com/simonepri/css-viewport-units-cross-browser/blob/master/library/viewport.js

Answer (score 16):

You can calculate vh in pixels with a line of code:

```
let _1vh = Math.round(window.innerHeight / 100)
```

So you can have a function for it:

```
function vhToPixels (vh) {
  return Math.round(window.innerHeight / (100 / vh)) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: document.documentElement.clientHeight is way taller than the screen and is unrelated to vh. It's as tall as the content of the page.

Comment: No that doesn't exist

Comment: Works great, for width too.

Comment: This isn't true for mobile devices, where `window.innerHeight` changes as the URL bar appears and disappears. In contrast, `100vh` is the viewport height when the URL bar is hidden. Here's a [nice article from the Google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing) about it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `offsetHeight` or `clientHeight` to get the height of an element in px.

> The `offsetHeight` property returns the viewable height of an element in pixels, including padding, border and scrollbar, but not the margin.
>
> The `clientHeight` property returns the viewable height of an element in pixels, including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin.

See the difference

```js
var vhele=document.getElementById('vhele')
function show()
{
    console.log(' clientHeight='+vhele.clientHeight+ 'px'+' , Height with padding and border= ' + vhele.offsetHeight + 'px' );
}
```

```css
body{
margin:0;
}
#vhele{
  padding:15px;
  border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="vhele" style='height:75vh;background:#AFB'>
                100vh
                
                <button onclick='show()' style='font-size:55px'>
                    Show
                </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like this is the only way. Always have an invisible div with height:100vh;width:0;position:absolute; and check its clientHeight.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that 100vh is taller than the visible viewport on purpose on mobile so that the browser bars can change size without altering vh. So I want the size of the screen regardless of the browser bars, which is what vh does.

This is important context that shouldn't be ignored. `window.innerHeight` does not always give you the height of an element with a height of `100vh`. `window.innerHeight` changes as the URL bar appears and disappears. In contrast, `100vh` is the viewport height only when the URL bar is hidden. Here is [a nice article from the developers at Google about this subject](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing).

I've come up with a solution that works for me. The best way to get the height of an element with a height of `100vh` is simply to create that element and measure it.

```html
<!-- See: `getFullVh()` -->
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0">
 <div id="measure-vh" style="position: fixed; height: 100vh"></div>
</div>
```

And then in your JavaScript:

```js
/** Return the "largest possible viewport" height in px.
 *
 * What is the "largest possible viewport" height?
 * https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing
 */
const getFullVh = () => {
  return document.querySelector('#measure-vh').clientHeight
}
```

> I also have my font size set to 10vh. What is that exactly in pixels?

Using `getFullVh()`:

```js
const tenVh = getFullVh() * 0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it because your missing this in a

```
 <head>
```

tag?

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: No. Okay I added that to the example page code and I still have no way of getting how tall 100vh is.

Comment: After adding the above code in between the head tags in your html, using window.document.body.clientHeight should now give you the 100vh equivalent in pixels.

Comment: Well it doesn't work. I updated the screenshot, and the code display. The working link was already updated to have the meta tag.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with most of the solutions is that window.innerHeight, screen.height, window.outerHeight, documentElement.clientHeight and so on are not reliable measures of the browser page size. The best way I've found is to create a rule yourself

```
const rule = document.createElement('div');
rule.style = 'width:0; height:100vh; position:fixed;';
insertAfter(someOtherElement, rule);
// Then you can use rule.clientHeight with a formula like
const vhToPx = (vh)=>(rule.clientHeight / (100 / vh)) + 'px'
```